# Using echo with PHP CLI?

Tags: echo, php

I'm running the following script in the PHP CLI:

```
<?php echo 'hello world!'; ?>
```

Nothing shows up. How can I enable output?

Comment: The script is okay. You are invoking it wrong.

Comment: How are you invoking this script?

Answer (score 21):

Run it in your terminal:

```
php -r 'echo "Hello World!\n";'
```

Comment: Hi @roman-newaza   I got error when i run in windows cmd: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''echo' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in Command line code on line 1 Can you guide? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Apoorva Try changing the quotation marks by each other

Comment: this worked for me `php71 -r 'echo "Hello World!\n";'`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you forgot the shebang line. Yours may vary depending on your setup, but you need to somehow point to php.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env php
 <?php echo 'hello world!'; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the user has permissions to run the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php -a (php interactive shell) :

```
php -a
echo 'helloworld';
```